# SQL how select parent id or id (if has not parent) of arguments

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have database with tables: products, product_colors, colors.

**Products** have attribute: *id, name, ...*

**Product_colors** have attribute: *id, products_id, colors_id*

**Colors** have attribute: *id, colors_id, name*

So that Product have row in product colors join by products.id=product_colors.products_id
and next connection to colors_id across product_colors.colors_id = colors.id

Products:

```
id     name
-------------------
1      produkt1
2      produkt2
3      produkt3
```

Product_colors:

```
id     products_id      colors_id
1      1                1 
2      1                5
3      2                1 
4      2                3
5      3                6
```

Colors can have parent across colors_id:

```
id     colors_id      name
__________________________________
1      null           red
2      null           green
3      1              flashred
4      2              kiwi 
5      2              lightgreen
6      null           black
```

Red 
 -> flashred, orange

Green 
 -> kiwi, lightgreen, darkgreen

How can i get all products which contains all parent colors(as parametr), if arguments colors is red and lightgreen -> Than selected product should have colors red and green exactly

So I need get parent of arguments color (if argument has not parent I take argument color), this parent colors give to array a by this array usin IN select products.
I want to this in MYSQL

```
SELECT products.id AS id
        FROM products
        LEFT JOIN product_colors
            ON products.id = product_colors.products_id
        LEFT JOIN colors
            ON product_colors.colors_id = colors.id
        WHERE colors.id IN (1,5)
```

1,5 are arguments

For arguments [1,5] I want get result product with id 1

Comment: See COALESCE().

Comment: Please do share the expected result.

Comment: Kumar_Vikas yes I added example table and i want for arguments color: 1,5 get product with id 1

Answer (score 0):

The solution will involve re-joining again to the COLORS table, to get the parent color data.

If you have another join like this:

```
LEFT JOIN colors PARENT_COLOR ON colors.colors_id = PARENT_COLOR.id
```

Then you can use this PARENT_COLOR table to show or filter results from this table.